# Cannot get device information on Ionic/Cordova App to appear

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic app and I am trying to display the device information as follows within my views.

Code (coffeeScript):

```
angular.module('hgApp', ['ionic'])
 .run(($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) ->
 aboutPageFunction($rootScope)
 $ionicPlatform.ready ->
deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device()
console.log(deviceInformation)
  if window.cordova and window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar true
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll true
  if window.StatusBar
    StatusBar.styleDefault()
  return
 return
).config [
'$stateProvider'
'$urlRouterProvider'
($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
$stateProvider.state('app',
  url: '/app'
  abstract: true
  templateUrl: './sections/menu/menu.tpl.html'
  controller: 'roomList'
).state('app.myHouse',
  url: '/myHouse'
  views:
    'menuContent':
      templateUrl: './sections/myHouse/myHouse.tpl.html'
)
# if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise 'app/myHouse'
return
]

aboutPageFunction = ($rootScope) ->
 device = ionic.Platform.device()
 $rootScope.currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform()
 $rootScope.currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version()
 $rootScope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer
 return
```

Template view

```
<ion-view view-title="About">
 <ion-content>
         <span>Manufacturer:>{{manufacturer}}</p></span>
        <span>Current platform:>{{currentPlatform}}</p></span>
        <span>Current platform version:>{{currentPlatformVersion}}</p></span>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view view-title="About">
```

I am using Chrome to setup an 'Google Nexus 5' device using the tools in the browser.

When I refresh the page it doesn't show manufacturer but it shows the latter two variables as show below:

```
Manufacturer:
Current platform: android
Current platform version: 6
```

Any ideas why the device object doesn't display the manufacturer info?

-- note --
When I console.log($ionicPlatform) within the ready() I get a valid object but do not see any device stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [cordova-plugin-device](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) to get the device's hardware and software details.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device);
}
```

properties device object:

```
device.cordova
device.model
device.platform
device.uuid
device.version
device.manufacturer
device.isVirtual
device.serial
```

UPDATE

The `$ionicPlatform.ready` execute a callback when the device is ready, so you don't really need to add a `deviceready`event listener:

```
angular.module('hgApp', ['ionic'])
 .run(($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) ->
 aboutPageFunction($rootScope)
 $ionicPlatform.ready ->

  if window.device
    console.log(device)

  if window.cordova and window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar true
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll true
  if window.StatusBar
    StatusBar.styleDefault()
  return
 return
)
```

Comment: thanks for that - i am trying to integrate this within an existing app - would you know the best approach to setup the addEventListener within my code above?

Comment: thanks that code looks to be perfect but for some reason the device variable is undefined. Strange as i'm using the same code on their own site 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

Comment: Did you installed the plugin? cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device

Comment: I have the plugin installed... using my code above I added a console.log to output the ionic.Platform.device()

I have the exact same issue as this person - the object is just empty?
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-platform-device-returns-empty-object/25646

i'll keep on it :)

Comment: Are you testing it on the device? Cordova plugins doesn't works in the browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104172/discussion-between-manzapanza-and-zabs).

Answer (score 1):

Just to write it more concisely for those looking for this answer:

1.) make sure to have `cordova-plugin-device` installed, you can check this in your config file or by running `cordova plugin ls`

2.) The user (and I) were trying to reference the device object as `ionic.Platform.device()`, which is how it's show at this link: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/utility/ionic.Platform/.
However, if you installed the above plugin, the device info you're looking for is actually found in `window.device`, or simply `device` if there are no local `device` variables.

Hope this helps.